# Error running script on existing element

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues running a script and getting and error on the `addEventListener` property. I understand that this occurs when I reference an element that doesn't exist in the DOM, but I'm running the script at the bottom of my markup, so I'm not sure what I need to change.

Script:

```
  var slideLeft = new Menu({
    wrapper: '#o-wrapper',
    type: 'slide-left',
    menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',
    maskId: '#c-mask'
  });

  var slideLeftBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--slide-left');

  slideLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    slideLeft.open();
  });
```

Example: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/ZBLeVQ

Working demo: http://callmenick.com/_development/slide-push-menus/

Comment: the only thing I can think of for this is to make sure you have the id correct

Comment: I tried your codepen and I get the same error. Copying the code to jsfiddle and I don't have an error...

Comment: Unrelated, but you probably mean `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: As written, your codepen isn't initializing the `Menu` properly, probably because of the missing IDs you specify in its options. When I add the missing IDs (more or less at random since your HTML is different than the tutorial) it at least runs, but doesn't display anything. FWIW it was pretty easy to get that far by just dumping in some `console.log`s and commenting out the `Menu` construction to prove it wasn't working. Then on to the `Menu` tutorial to see the DOM elements you left out.

Comment: You forgot the wrapper tag and the mask div for menu. Please follow document http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions

Comment: Thanks, guys. I neglected to check the other elements too. Added them in and resolved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

**I updated the CodePen:** http://codepen.io/HenryGranados/pen/rWjmVj

**Here's a working solution. Hope it helps :)**

```js
var slideLeft = new Menu({
    wrapper: '#o-wrapper',
    type: 'slide-left',
    menuOpenerClass: '.c-button',
    maskId: '#c-mask'
  });

  var slideLeftBtn = document.querySelector('#c-button--slide-left');
  
  slideLeftBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    slideLeft.open();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://callmenick.com/_development/slide-push-menus/css/style.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://callmenick.com/_development/slide-push-menus/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://callmenick.com/_development/slide-push-menus/js/dist/menu.js"></script>

<main class="o-content">
  <div class="o-container">
    <div class="c-buttons">
      <button id="c-button--slide-left" class="c-button">Slide Left</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<div id="o-wrapper" class="o-wrapper">
</div>

<nav id="c-menu--slide-left" class="c-menu c-menu--slide-left">
  <button class="c-menu__close">&larr; Close Menu</button>
  <ul class="c-menu__items">
    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">About</a></li>
    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">Services</a></li>
    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">Work</a></li>
    <li class="c-menu__item"><a href="#" class="c-menu__link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="c-mask" class="c-mask"></div>
```